# Convert string to Date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datejs

I want to compare these Strings`2013-11-04 13:10:22.0`, `2013-11-04 13:08:03.0` through JavaScript, jQuery or any other library. Is there any way to convert these Strings into Date Type?

I searched this in google and Stack Overflow and found that JavaScript is not good at DateTime formats.

Actually I get JSON data from Server through `jQuery.Ajax`, My JSON object looks like this

```
{"RecieverEmail": "email@gmail.com",
 "Message": "Hello Ankit",
 "DateTime": "2013-11-04 13:08:03.0"
 }
```

and when I parse this Date format using Date.parse method

```
var d = Date.parse(data.DateTime);
alert(d);
```

it alerts `1383550683000`

Answer (score 1):

Moment.js is a great library for this: http://momentjs.com/

You can pass that exact string in and format it the way you want or call `.toDate()`on it to get a JavaScript date object.

Answer (score 1):

Parse like this

```
var d = new Date(data.DateTime);
alert(d);
```

> because the **`Date.parse()`** method parses a string representation of a date, and
>   returns the number of milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Momment.js" . It is the free version and it is very simple to handle this type of operation.

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var d = Date.parse(data.DateTime);
var realDate = new Date(d);
alert(realDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the Date be  "2013-11-04" make it to a Date Object as

`var d=new Date(Date.parse("2013-11-04"));`

Answer (score 0):

for compare you can use this number because Date.parse return the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few good `jQuery` plugins out there that make dealing with dates a little bit easier.  I would also recommend `Moment.js` since it is the easier to use and more flexible in my opinion.

Here is a fiddle that converts your json datetime into a date object
http://jsfiddle.net/kLMMg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as:

```
var a = {"RecieverEmail": "email@gmail.com",
    "Message": "Hello Ankit",
    "DateTime": "2013-11-04 13:08:03.0"
}
alert(new Date(a.DateTime))
```